# Why isn't div height changed?

Tags: html, css

Yo, I have a div, which I've tried to give a specific height for ages. It refuses to cooperate. I can change the width, but not the height. Does anybody know maybe a reason why? Any properties that can affect my ability to set specific div sizes?

Here's my HTML, and although I have the same problem with every div, it is the div with tag "priser" which frustrates me the most. I'll give you a picture to show how it leads to different placement from browser to browser (the rectangle called "Prisinformasjon" is the output of the "priser"-div):

[image]

```html
<form method='POST' id='form1' runat='server' autocomplete='off'>

        <div id="screenie" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; font-family: 'Malgun Gothic'; font-weight: 400;">
        <div style="margin-top: 15px;">
            
            <div id="Tjenesteinformasjon" style='width: 300px; height: 335px; text-align: center; position: absolute; left: 30px; border-radius: 18px; border-color: #ff3333; border-style: solid; border-width: 6px; padding: 10px 10px;'>
                <span style='font-size: 26px;'>Hva gjør vi?</span><br />
                    
                <p style='color:black;'>Vi tilbyr flyttehjelp, flyttevask, varetaxi/budbil, transport og utleie av biltransporthenger!<br /><br />
                Vennligst benytt bestillingsskjema til høyre for å få et tilbud raskt og enkelt (bestilling er ikke bindende)!<br /><br />
                Ønsker du å kontakte oss manuelt, enten for bestilling, informasjon eller kundeservice, kan du også bruke kontakt- og bedriftsinformasjonen nedenfor.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="Center-div" style="width: 550px; position: absolute; left: 380px;">
                <div style='color: black;  border-radius: 18px; border-color: #ff3333; border-style: solid; border-width: 6px; padding: 10px 10px;'>
                <div style="text-align: center;">

                <div id="skjematype_a" style="display: block; width: 265px; height: 75px; margin-left: 120px; color: black; font-size: 11.75px; text-align: center; border-width: 3px; border-style: outset; border-color: #00e6ab;">
                    <img id="bil" src="/images/bil.jpg" onclick="changeImage()" style="width: 135px; height: 75px; float: left; padding-right: 2px;" />
                    <div id="skjematype_b">Klikk på bildet for å bytte bestillingskjema til <b>biltransporthenger.</b></div>
                </div>

                <script>
                    function changeImage()
                    {
                        var bestillingstekst = document.getElementById('bestillingstekst')
                        var bestillingstekst2 = document.getElementById('bestillingstekst2')
                        var block = document.getElementById('skjematype_a')
                        var s_text = document.getElementById('skjematype_b')
                        var image = document.getElementById('bil');
                        if (image.src.match("bil"))
                            {
                            image.src = "/images/henger.jpg"
                            s_text.innerHTML = "Klikk på bildet for å bytte bestillingskjema til <b>transport</b> og <b>flyttetjenester.</b>"
                            bestillingstekst.hidden = 'hidden'
                            bestillingstekst2.hidden = ''
                            }
                        else
                            {
                            image.src = "/images/bil.jpg";
                            s_text.innerHTML = "Klikk på bildet for å bytte bestillingskjema til <b>biltransporthenger.</b>"
                            bestillingstekst.hidden = ''
                            bestillingstekst2.hidden = 'hidden'
                            }
                    }
                </script>
                
                <div id='bestillingstekst' class='bestillingstekst'>
                    <p>
                        <span style='font-size: 26px;'>Bli kontaktet med tilbud på sms!</span><br />
                        <span style='font-style: italic;'>(tilbudet kommer normalt dagen etter)</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class='question'>Hvilke tjenester ønsker du?</p>

                        <label>Flyttehjelp<input id='fhjelp' type='checkbox' name='tjenester' runat='server'/></label>
                        <label>Flyttevask<input id='fvask' type='checkbox' name='tjenester' runat='server'/></label></>
                        <label>Transport<input id='transport' type='checkbox' name='tjenester' runat='server'/></label></>
                    

                    <p class='question'>Hvordan ønsker du å betale?</p>

                        <label>Kontant<input id='kontant' type='radio' name='betaling' runat='server'/></label></>
                        <label>Faktura<input id='faktura' type='radio' name='betaling' runat='server'/></label></>
                    
                    <p class="question">Hva synes du er en god pris for jobben?</p>
                        <div style='width: 100%; display: inline-block; text-align: left; line-height: 22px;'>
                            <label>Pris i kroner:<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='pris1' type='tel' maxlength='8' runat='server'/></label>
                        </div>

                    <p class='question'>Er du privatperson eller bedrift?</p>

                        <label>Privat<input id='privat' type='radio' name='kundetype' runat='server'/></label></>
                        <label>Bedrift<input id='bedrift' type='radio' name='kundetype' runat='server'/></label></>
                    

                    <p class='question'>Hvordan kontakter vi deg?</p>

                    <div style='width: 100%; display: inline-block; text-align: left; line-height: 23px;'>
                        <label>Fullt personnavn<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='personnavn' type='text' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Bedriftsnavn<span class='psmall'> (kun for bedrifter)</span><input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='bedriftsnavn' type='text' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Mobilnr.<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='tlf' type='tel' maxlength='8' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Alternativt telefonnr.<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='alt_tlf' type='tel' maxlength='8' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Epost<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='epost' type='email' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />
                    
                    </div>

                    <p class='question'>Hva er beste dato og tidspunkt for tjenesten(e)?</p>
                    <p class='psmall2'>(bare endr tidspunkt for tjenestene du skal ha)</p>
                    
                    <div style='width: 100%; display: inline-block; text-align: left; line-height: 24.5px;'>
                        <label>Flyttehjelp<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='fhjelp_tid' type='datetime-local'  value='2020-01-01T10:00:00' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Utflyttingsvask<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='fvask_tid' type='datetime-local'  value='2020-01-01T10:00:00' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Tilflyttingsvask<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='fvask_tid2' type='datetime-local'  value='2020-01-01T10:00:00' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Transport<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='transport_tid' type='datetime-local'  value='2020-01-01T10:00:00' runat='server'/></label> 
                        <br />

                    </div>

                    <p class='question'>Hvor skal tjenesten(e) starte?</p>

                    <div style='width: 100%; display: inline-block; text-align: left; line-height: 23px;'>
                        <label>Adresse<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='adresse1' type='text' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Poststed<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='poststed1' type='text' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Postnr.<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='postnr1' type='text' maxlength='4' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Etasje<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='etasje1' type='tel' maxlength='2' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Ca. kvadratmeter <span class='psmall'>(trengs bare ved utflyttingsvask)</span><input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='kvadratmeter1' type='tel' maxlength='8' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Bygningstype<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='bygningstype1' type='text' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Heis?</label>
                        <div style='display: inline-block; float:right;'>
                            <label>Ja<input id='heisja1' type='radio' name='heis1' runat='server'/></label>
                            <label>Nei<input id='heisnei1' type='radio' name='heis1' class='radioleft' runat='server'/></label>
                        </div>
                        <br />

                    </div>
                        
                    <p class='question'>Hvor skal tjenesten(e) avslutte(s)?</p>
                    <p class='psmall2'>(ikke fyll inn viss kun utflyttingsvask)</p>

                    <div style='width: 100%; display: inline-block; text-align: left; line-height: 23px;'>
                        <label>Adresse<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='adresse2' type='text' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Poststed<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='poststed2' type='text' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Postnr.<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='postnr2' type='text' maxlength='4' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Etasje<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='etasje2' type='tel' maxlength='2' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Ca. kvadratmeter <span class='psmall'>(trengs bare ved tilflyttingsvask)</span><input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='kvadratmeter2' type='tel' maxlength='8' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Bygningstype<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='bygningstype2' type='text' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Heis?</label>
                        <div style='display: inline-block; float:right;'>
                            <label>Ja<input id='heisja2' type='radio' name='heis2' runat='server'/></label>
                            <label>Nei<input id='heisnei2' type='radio' name='heis2' class='radioleft' runat='server'/></label>
                        </div>
                        <br />

                    </div>
                        
                    <p class='question'>Hva ønsker du fraktet (og annet vi bør vite)?</p>
                    <textarea id='textarea1' rows='6' cols='32' spellcheck='False' name='S1' runat='server'>Du behøver ikke skrive noe her viss du ikke trenger det...</textarea><br />
                    <button style='margin-top: 2px;' id='Button2' form='form1' type='submit' onserverclick='sendemail' runat='server'>Kontakt meg med et tilbud!</button>
                </div>

                <div hidden="hidden" id='bestillingstekst2' class='bestillingstekst'>
                
                     <p>
                        <span style='font-size: 26px;'>Bli kontaktet med tilbud på sms!</span><br />
                        <span style='font-style: italic;'>(tilbudet kommer normalt dagen etter)</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class='question'>Hvordan ønsker du å betale?</p>

                        <label>Kontant<input id='leie_kontant' type='radio' name='betaling' runat='server'/></label></>
                        <label>Faktura<input id='leie_faktura' type='radio' name='betaling' runat='server'/></label></>

                    <p class="question">Hva synes du er en god pris for leie?</p>
                    <p class='psmall2'>(fastpriser inntil 1 døgn: 300kr/400kr/500kr under 4/8/24 timer)</p>
                        <div style='width: 100%; display: inline-block; text-align: left; line-height: 23px;'>
                            <label>Pris i kroner:<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='pris2' type='tel' maxlength='8' runat='server'/></label>
                        </div>
                
                    <p class='question'>Er du privatperson eller bedrift?</p>

                        <label>Privat<input id='leie_privat' type='radio' name='kundetype' runat='server'/></label></>
                        <label>Bedrift<input id='leie_bedrift' type='radio' name='kundetype' runat='server'/></label></>
                    

                    <p class='question'>Hvordan kontakter vi deg?</p>

                    <div style='width: 100%; display: inline-block; text-align: left; line-height: 23px;'>
                        <label>Fullt personnavn<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='leie_personnavn' type='text' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Bedriftsnavn<span class='psmall'> (kun for bedrifter)</span><input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='leie_bedriftsnavn' type='text' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Mobilnr.<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='leie_tlf' type='tel' maxlength='8' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Alternativt telefonnr.<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='leie_alt_tlf' type='tel' maxlength='8' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Epost<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='leie_epost' type='email' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />
                    
                    </div>

                    <p class='question'>Når ønsker du å leie?</p>
                    
                    <div style='width: 100%; display: inline-block; text-align: left; line-height: 24.5px;'>
                        <label>Leiestart<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='leiestart' type='datetime-local'  value='2020-01-01T10:00:00' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Leieslutt<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='leieslutt' type='datetime-local'  value='2020-01-01T10:00:00' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                    </div>

                    <p class='question'>Hva er adressen din?</p>

                    <div style='width: 100%; display: inline-block; text-align: left; line-height: 23px;'>
                        <label>Adresse<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='leie_adresse' type='text' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Poststed<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='leie_poststed' type='text' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                        <label>Postnr.<input style='width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:right;' id='leie_postnr' type='text' maxlength='4' runat='server'/></label>
                        <br />

                    </div>

                    <p class='question'>Noe mer vi bør vite?</p>
                    <textarea id='textarea2' rows='6' cols='32' spellcheck='False' name='S1' runat='server'>Du behøver ikke skrive noe her viss du ikke trenger det...</textarea><br />
                    <button style='margin-top: 2px;' id='Button1' form='form1' type='submit' onserverclick='sendemail2' runat='server'>Kontakt meg med et tilbud!</button>
                </div>

                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <img style="width: 315px; height: 245px; position:absolute; left: 955px;" src='/images/logo.jpg'/ alt='logo'/>
            
            <div id="Priser" style="width: 300px; position:absolute; left: 45px; top: 375px">
            <div style="text-align: center; color: black; border-radius: 18px; border-color: #ff3333; border-style: solid; border-width: 6px; padding: 10px 10px;">
                <span style='font-size: 26px;'>Prisinformasjon:</span><br />
                <p>
                    Priser avtales som en fast sum på forhånd! Du skal aldri betale mer enn denne prisen!<br />
                    <span style="color: red; font-weight: 600; font-size: 19px;">Det er viktig for oss at du er fornøyd med prisen din! Derfor kan du gi oss et tilbud i bestillingskjema til høyre! Ikke glem å fortell oss hva du ønsker!</span>
                </p>
            </div>
            </div>

             <div id="Kontaktinformasjon" style='width: 300px; height: 190px; position:absolute; left: 30px; top: 700px; text-align: center; border-radius: 18px; border-color: #ff3333; border-style: solid; border-width: 6px; padding: 10px 10px;'>
                <span style='font-size: 26px;'>Hvordan kontakte oss?</span><br />
                    
                <p style='color:black;'>epost: post@hjelpsommefolk.no<br />tlf: 92 53 48 35<br/>Organisasjonsnr.: 916 043 112<br/>
                Postadresse: Nøsteveien 60, 3413 Lier<br/>Kontaktperson: Mantas Tamosiunas</p>
            </div>

            <div id="Finn" style='width: 300px; height: 265px; position:absolute; left: 950px; top: 265px; text-align: center; border-radius: 18px; border-color: #ff3333; border-style: solid; border-width: 6px; padding: 10px 10px;'>
                <p style="font-size: 16px; font-style: italic;">Se våre finn.no referanser i linken under! <a href="http://www.finn.no/smajobber/profiler/510702027/">http://www.finn.no/smajobber...</a></p>
                <img  style="" src='/images/finn1.PNG'/>
                <img  style="" src='/images/finn2.PNG'/>
                <img  style="" src='/images/finn3.PNG'/>
            </div>

            <div id="Facebook" style="width: 300px; position:absolute; left: 965px; top: 580px;">
                <div style="text-align: center;">        
                <div style="color: black; border-radius: 18px; border-color: #ff3333; border-style: solid; border-width: 6px; padding: 10px 10px;">
                <h4 style="font-style: italic;">
                    Liker du oss? Vis det her! <3
                </h4>

                <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://hjelpsommefolk.no" data-width="100" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
                <br />
                <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://hjelpsommefolk.no" data-width="275" data-numposts="6"></div>
                
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var screen_width_string = ((screen.width * 0.5)-(1265*0.5)-30);
            var screen_width_string = screen_width_string + "px";
            document.getElementById('screenie').style.marginLeft = screen_width_string;
        </script>

    </form>
```

Comment: While I realise that browser compatibility can be a big issue, I have to wonder, does it really matter that they're not pixel-for-pixel the same?

Comment: The problem isn't so much that the browsers differ, but that I'm unable to get a consistent distance between red-coloured divs in both browsers. It looks unprofessional (and I do this as a small part-time but professional job) and aesthetically disturbing. If you look, you can see that in firefox, the div bordering at the top has the correct distance to the next div, but at the bottom the two browsers suddenly decide to give it different length.

Comment: Oh I see, so it's more that the indicated box doesn't have the same margin at the bottom than it does at the top, am I understanding correctly?

Comment: I don't use the margin property to set the distance because margin makes it very complicated, I use absolute positions. But else, yes.

Comment: Ah, well, that's your problem then. When you start using `absolute` positions, you start getting into fights with the browser to make everything the same height, which is a losing battle to fight. I'd suggest trying to make it work with margins, as it will make things much simpler if done right.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a "height" rule on your "Priser" div or its contents. Adding one does work, though easily leads to content collisions due to your overuse of absolute positioning.  (You should really consider basing your CSS on classes instead of doing it inline, it'll be much easier to read and debug and you'll be able to reuse rules on multiple elements, which is one of the main benefits of CSS.)

Comment: Only use absolute positioning if unavoidable and where it absolutely makes sense. In this case you can just position the divs relatively to where they should be.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to work with margins to adjust it at the end since it is where it's  not showing properly. As said by Niet, there is no way to win a battle with browsers when using absolute positioning, at least at the moment.